# What type is this diffirental equation and how can i solve it?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this differential equation? What type is it?

$$\frac{d}{dx} f(x)= a - a \cdot f(x) - 5 \cdot f^2(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a Riccati equation. You either guess a solution to transform it into a Bernoulli equation, or you substitute $f(x)=\frac{g'(x)}{5g(x)}$ to get a second order linear equation.

In this case with constant coefficients you also have the choice to treat it as a separable equation and solve it via a partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=f(x),$ then this becomes $\mathrm dy=(a-ay-5y^2)\mathrm dx,$ or whenever the coefficient of $\mathrm dx$ does not vanish, we have $$\frac{\mathrm dy}{a-ay-5y^2}=\mathrm dx,$$ which can be easily integrated. In the case where the quadratic in $y$ vanishes, the equation becomes $\mathrm dy=0\cdot\mathrm dx,$ which implies that $y$ is some function independent of $x,$ that is, constant with respect to $x.$ You can get the exact form of $y$ in this case by solving the algebraic equation $$a-ay-5y^2=0.$$